# amazon_product_review_scraper returns certificate verify failed

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm running the following code:

```
from amazon_product_review_scraper import amazon_product_review_scraper
review_scraper = amazon_product_review_scraper(amazon_site="amazon.in", product_asin="B098RKWHHZ")
reviews_df = review_scraper.scrape()
reviews_df.head(5)
```

and I get the following:

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='sslproxies.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))
```

I have installed certifi  but did not help.

Comment: If you tryied everything and they all didn't work, you can disable certificate verification temporarily by `ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context`. But keep in mind that disabling certificate verification is not safe.

Comment: How should I run this command? in the terminal?

Comment: not in terminal, run on python. `import ssl`

Comment: I've tried to run it in the same snippet but did not work